# Choosing an embedding feature dimension

Tags: neural-network, embeddings

I'm trying to tackle a classification problem with a neural net tensor using flow.
I have some continuous variable features and some categorical features. 
The continuous features are normalized using sklearn's StandardScaler.
For the categorical features I am using a series of embedding features that I'm concatenating together with my continuous features.

The embedding features are created like so :

```
 airline = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(
        'AIRLINE', hash_bucket_size=10)
```

then :

```
 tf.feature_column.embedding_column(airline, 8)
```

However I am having trouble choosing my ***embedding feature output size***. I understand this transforms my sparse one hot encode "airline" feature into a float vector of size 8.

**Is there a heuristic I can use to choose an embedding feature size ?**

My neural net's accuracy remains stuck at 31%. It doesn't seem to be learning even after a 100 epochs. Could the size of the embedding features be a cause for such a behaviour ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think post below is a good resource.

https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/introducing-tensorflow-feature-columns.html

Basically, all categorical variable is initially converted to one-hot encoding, then layer size defined by `dimension` argument is stacked on top of one-hot encoding; thus learning optimal representation of categorical variable based on specified dimension.

There is general rule in the blog post to take the 4th root of the number of categories.

Another approach is to perform MDS to inspect your categorical variables to decide dimensions.

Comment: PCA is not suitable for categorical variables.

Comment: @DavidMarx you are right! Edited the original post!